# Alternatives to XMLStreamReader which can read bytes directly

Tags: java, xml, stax

Are there any alternatives to XMLStreamReader or XMLEventReader which can retrieve attribute values and contents of elements at CHARACTER events as byte arrays directly, without creating String instances or allocating char[] arrays and converting them to byte[] later?